# apache JMeter JMS Point-to-Point for sending XML type messages

Tags: jms, jmeter

Can I use JMS Point-to-Point for sending XML type messages to a Q ?

Answer (score 1):

XML messages are just plain text messages, so that should be perfectly doable.